# Dataframe - Create a column based on another with IF formulas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling with this rather complex calculated column.

[image: pandas]

The cumulative sum is watts of light.

It changes to 0 when the system resets it to a new day. So the 24hour day is sunrise to sunrise.

I want to use this fact to calculate a 'Date 2' that I can them summarize in the future to report average 24hr day temp, light etc.

For the First 0 **Cumulative Sum** of every **Date**, **Date** + 1 Day, Else the last row of **Date 2**.

I have been playing around with the following, assuming **Advanced Date** is a copy of **Cumulative Sum**:

```
for i in range(1, len(ClimateDF)):
    j = ClimateDF.columns.get_loc('AdvancedDate')

    if ClimateDF.iat[i, j] == 0 and ClimateDF.iat[i - 1, j] != 0:

        print(ClimateDF.iat[i, j])
       # ClimateDF.iat[i, 'AdvancedDate'] = 'New Day' #this doesn't work
        ClimateDF['AdvancedDate'].values[i] = 1

    else:

        print(ClimateDF.iat[i, j])
        #ClimateDF.iat[i, 'AdvancedDate'] = 'Not New Day' #this doesn't work
        ClimateDF['AdvancedDate'].values[i] = 2
```

This doesn't quite do what I want, but I thought I was close. However when I change:

**ClimateDF['AdvancedDate'].values[i] = 1**

to

**ClimateDF['AdvancedDate'].values[i] = ClimateDF['Date'].values[i]**

I get a:

**TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'**

Am I on the right track? How do I get past this error? Is there a more efficient way I could be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can first create a `cumsum` reflecting day change, and then calculate `Date_2` by adding it to the first date:

```
s = (df["sum"].eq(0)&df["sum"].shift().ne(0)).cumsum()

df["Date_2"] = df["Datetime"][0]+pd.to_timedelta(s,unit="D") #base on first day to calculate offset for all days
```

Comment: This works - I just had to do (s-1,unit="D"). This condenses around 25 lines I had to 3! Could you explain how it is working? For example how does it deal with there being two zeros next to each other?

Comment: I think I figured it out. If the sum == 0 AND the sum one row above == 0, it will return TRUE and cumulative sum these up. You then add this sum to the date in the very first row of the Datetime. Excellent!

Comment: To be exact its sum ==0 and the sum one row above `!= 0`, but you get the idea.